# ExpandoObject with Select Clause

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, types

I have to populate below class in Linq Query

```
public class Emp             
{       
    public string name {get; set;}      
    public dynamic Obj { get; set; }       
    public Emp()
    {
        Obj = new ExpandoObject();
    }  
}

public LoadData()  
{
   var emp = (from d in dbContext.Employees         
              select new Emp   
              {  
                 name = d.name,  
                 Obj.DOB = d.DOB,  
                 Obj.BirthPlace = d.BirthPlace  
              }).ToList();

}

OR

    public LoadData()  
    {
       var emp = (from d in dbContext.Employees         
                  select new Emp   
                  {  
                     name = d.name,  
                    Obj.DOB = new ExpandoObject { DOB = d.DOB, BirthPlace =   d.BirthPlace }      }).ToList();

    }
```

it doesn't allow me to assign properties dynamically like above, Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var emp = (from d in dbContext.Employees
          select new Emp
          {
             name = d.name,
             Obj = { DOB = d.DOB, BirthPlace = d.BirthPlace }
}).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var emp = (from d in dbContext.Employees         
          select new Emp   
          {  
             name = d.name,  
             Obj = { DOB = d.DOB, BirthPlace = d.BirthPlace } 
          }).ToList();
```

It is very similar to @gowansg answer, but without `new` keyword. It is just setting of values of properties. If we will try to get `Type` of `Obj` we will recieve `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`. With `new` keyword it will be some anonymous type.
respectively, such constructions like:

```
emp[0].Obj.OtherProperty = 1;
```

will fail in case of using anonymous type.

Comment: Good catch. I typed the `new` out of habit, without considering the consequences.

Comment: what if we want to use query like structure of linq i.e. from d in dbContext.Employees  ...

Comment: @Tejas Patel, do you mean `method chain`? In this example `from d in dbContext.Employees` construction is already used.

Answer (score 0):

You were close in your second example, you just need to set `Obj` equal to a `new anonymous object` instead of a `new ExpandoObject`:

```
var emp = (from d in dbContext.Employees         
          select new Emp   
          {  
             name = d.name,  
             Obj = new { DOB = d.DOB, BirthPlace = d.BirthPlace }
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Tejas declared `Obj` as `dyanmic` and not `EpxandoObject`, that's why this works.  If @Tejas were to use this method he should keep in mind that `Obj` is now an `anonymous type` and not an `ExpandoObject`, as @Alexander pointed out.